# Any scientific research papers on electromagnetic active valves using variable viscosity electromagnetic fluids?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, hydraulics, electromagnetism, hydrodynamics

I know the title is quite a mouthful, but let me explain (also, I couldn't find anything on the subject, maybe because I'm using the wrong words).

I saw some time ago [a video about a variable suspension system](https://youtu.be/8JspshhWruQ?t=299) that used a variable viscosity fluid that changes its viscosity based on a electromagnetic field applied to it (it is just a fluid with ferromagnetic particles on it [*I think*]).

(The link redirects to the video in the exact moment its working mechanism is explained).

To me it seems quite an interesting system that could allow for solenoid/active valves with no moving parts that can instantaneously and progressively change the flow of its fluids by changing its viscosity until nothing can flow.

But I couldn't find any papers on the subject, this makes me wonder if such system would even work...

Of course, I don't think it would be able to withstand the absurd pressures on industrial hydraulic systems, but smaller (maybe hobbyist) things.

Comment: search on *electrorheological fluids*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes magnetorheological dampers (MRDs) are practical and available on cars today. I get about a zillion google hits on them

An overview is here

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-84800-231-9_6

This looks interesting

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9633028

Pressure wise automotive dampers don't work at much more than 1700 psi, which is low for a hydraulic system, but in the same ballpark (4000 psi). I can't think of any intrinsic reason why MRD wouldn't work at a the higher pressure.